# Import data from MS SQL Server to HBase with Flume

Tags: sql-server, bigdata, hbase, flume

I'm really new to Flume. I prefer Flume than Sqoop because data is continued to be imported to MS SQL Server in my case, therefore I think Flume is a better choice which is able to transfer data in real time.

I just followed some online example and then editing my own flume config file which tells something about the source, channel, and sink. However, it seemed that Flume didn't work successfully. There was no data being transferred to HBase.

**mssql-hbase.conf**

```
# source, channel, sink
agent1.sources = src1
agent1.channels = ch1
agent1.sinks = sk1

# declare source type
agent1.sources.src1.type = org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:sqlserver://xx.xx.xx.xx:1433;DatabaseName=xxxx
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.user = xxxx
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.password = xxxx
agent1.sources.src1.table = xxxx

agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.autocommit = true

# declare mysql hibernate dialect
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
#agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
#agent1.sources.src1.columns.to.select = *
#agent1.sources.src1.incremental.column.name = PK, name, machine, time
#agent1.sources.src1.start.from=0
#agent1.sources.src1.incremental.value = 0

# query time interval
agent1.sources.src1.run.query.delay = 5000

# declare the folder loaction where flume state is saved
agent1.sources.src1.status.file.path = /home/user/flume-source-state
agent1.sources.src1.status.file.name = src1.status

agent1.sources.src1.batch.size = 1000
agent1.sources.src1.max.rows = 1000
agent1.sources.src1.delimiter.entry = |

# set the channel to memory mode
agent1.channels.ch1.type = memory
agent1.channels.ch1.capacity = 10000
agent1.channels.ch1.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent1.channels.ch1.byteCapacityBufferPercentage = 20
agent1.channels.ch1.byteCapacity = 800000

# declare sink type
agent1.sinks.sk1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
agent1.sinks.sk1.table = yyyy
agent1.sinks.sk1.columnFamily = yyyy
agent1.sinks.sk1.hdfs.batchSize = 100
agent1.sinks.sk1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer
agent1.sinks.sk1.serializer.regex = ^\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"$
agent1.sinks.sk1.serializer.colNames = PK, name, machine, time

# bind source, channel, sink
agent1.sources.src1.channels = ch1
agent1.sinks.sk1.channel = ch1
```

But, I use a similar config file to transfer data from MySql to HBase. Luckily, it worked.

**mysql-hbase.conf**

```
# source, channel, sink
agent1.sources = src1
agent1.channels = ch1
agent1.sinks = sk1

# declare source type
agent1.sources.src1.type = org.keedio.flume.source.SQLSource
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://xxxx:3306/userdb
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.user = xxxx
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.password = xxxx
agent1.sources.src1.table = xxxx

agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.autocommit = true

# declare mysql hibernate dialect
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
#agent1.sources.src1.hibernate.provider_class=org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider
#agent1.sources.src1.columns.to.select = *
#agent1.sources.src1.incremental.column.name = id
#agent1.sources.src1.incremental.value = 0

# query time interval
agent1.sources.src1.run.query.delay = 5000

# declare the folder loaction where flume state is saved
agent1.sources.src1.status.file.path = /home/user/flume-source-state
agent1.sources.src1.status.file.name = src1.status

#agent1.sources.src1.interceptors=i1
#agent1.sources.src1.interceptors.i1.type=search_replace
#agent1.sources.src1.interceptors.i1.searchPattern="
#agent1.sources.src1.interceptors.i1.replaceString=,

# Set the channel to memory mode
agent1.channels.ch1.type = memory
agent1.channels.ch1.capacity = 10000
agent1.channels.ch1.transactionCapacity = 10000
agent1.channels.ch1.byteCapacityBufferPercentage = 20
agent1.channels.ch1.byteCapacity = 800000

# declare sink type
agent1.sinks.sk1.type = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.HBaseSink
agent1.sinks.sk1.table = user_test_2
agent1.sinks.sk1.columnFamily = user_hobby
agent1.sinks.sk1.hdfs.batchSize = 100
agent1.sinks.sk1.serializer = org.apache.flume.sink.hbase.RegexHbaseEventSerializer
agent1.sinks.sk1.serializer.regex = ^\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\",\"(.*?)\"$
agent1.sinks.sk1.serializer.colNames = id,name,age,hobby

# bind source, channel, sink
agent1.sources.src1.channels = ch1
agent1.sinks.sk1.channel = ch1
```

Does anyone know is there something wrong in the config file? Thanks.